Continued fractions of $\sum_{n=0}^k 1/n!$
Quantities $\sum_{n=0}^k 1/n!$ approximate $e$, but not very well by the standards of Diophantine approximation.  One gets errors $|e-a/b|$ of roughly $1/(b\ln b)$ where one might hope for $c/b^2$
for some $c$.
Now $e$ has a beautiful, well-structured simple continued fraction expansion.
Of course the first coefficients (partial quotients?) of the continued fraction expansion of
$\sum_{n=0}^k 1/n!$ must agree with those of $e$. Indeed, the coefficients agree up to about the halfway point.  The previous paragraph suggests a heuristic that might predict that.
Can a theorem in this direction be proved?
It would also be interesting to know if the coefficients that occur after the two coefficient sequences diverge collectively (so as $K$ varies) conform to Gauss-Kuz'min statistics.

By "about half", do you mean the first half?

Yes.  Edited now to make that clear.

Certainly the partial quotients of $e$ don't conform to Gauss-Kuzmin. The truncated series for $e$ is rational, hence has only finitely many partial quotients, so it's not clear what could be meant by conformity to Gauss-Kuzmin.

The observation is that up to about the halfway point, the partial quotients of each $\sum_{n=0}^k 1/n!$ looks like partial partial quotients of $e$ and then, after that, they don't.  I'm asking about the "after that" statistics.  Of course for each $k$ there are only finitely many partial quotients, but as $k$ varies there are, altogether, infinitely many statistics, and I'm asking about their distribution.

I skimmed some articles and found this related article: "Diophantine approximation of the exponential function and Sondowʼs Conjecture"

Yes, approximately half of the partial quotients from continued fraction expansion (CFE) of $P_n/Q_n:=\sum_{k=0}^n 1/k!$ must coincide with partial quotients of the number $e$. Denominators $q_n$ of convergents $p_n/q_n$ to the number $e$ grow in a regular way (see S. Lang, Introduction to Diophantine approximations, section V.2):
$$c_14^m\Gamma(m+3/2)\le q_{3m+1}\le c_24^m\Gamma(m+3/2).$$
So if $$e-\frac{P_n}{Q_n}\approx\frac1{n\cdot n!}<e-\frac{p_{2m}}{q_{2m}}\approx\frac1{a_{2m+1}q_{2m}^2}$$
then the first $2m$ partial quotients of $P_n/Q_n$ are the same as in the CFE of $e$. Roughly speaking the parameters $m$ and $n$ are related by the formula $n!=q_{2m}^2$ where the growth of the denominators $q_m$ is given by the inequalities above.
It is very likely that the tail of the CFE of $P_n/Q_n$  conforms to Gauss–Kuz'min statistics. There is a similar conjecture for harmonic numbers $H_n$. But it is not clear how one can prove it. We don't have any averaging in this situation, and for particular numbers the situation is so far hopeless.
